SQL server sum function output
I am using this sum syntax
Select Sum(listsize), financial_year
from population_mapping
where financial_year>'2018'
group by financial_year

However the results are outputting as 6.2378057E7. How to i change this to a whole number without the E7 at the end.

have you tried to cast the data type? cast(sum(cast(listsize as bigint)) as bigint) or  sum(listsize::bigint)::biginton postgresql?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
